# Tracingback a Python function

Tags: python, traceback

A way I usually use to understand a project architecture in C++ is to set a break point in a particular function using GDB, and then using the traceback feature, I can easily understand the function calls between the different classes. I am totally new to Python and I want to ask what are the best Technics used to understand the Python project,

I took a look at `traceback` but the problem is that it is only tracing the functions inside the same module, so if the caller is in a different module it won't be traced. Besides, the size of the stack is also limited, correct me if I am wrong.

Could you please share the Technics you are using based on your own experience.

Comment: I am using the library ipdb which I find very useful in Python ! You should take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got the idea that python's tracebacks would be limited to a single module or limited in size - when an exception occurs, you *of course* have the *full* stack trace available.

This being said, [Python has a full step debugger in it's stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), which lets you inspect and navigate the whole call stack. And there are of course third-part step debuggers in various IDEs and custom shells or environments (ie IPython etc).

NB the `inspect` module might also [be of interest to you](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) - and not only for stack inspection ;-)